# Run hook on new buffer

Tags: hooks, projectile, uniquify

I am trying to create something like `uniquely`, which renames the buffer to the full path within the `projectile` project. I have the code working, however, I can't seem to figure out how to get it to run when a new buffer is open. It seems like Emacs does not provide any hooks for when a new buffer is opened.

What is a good way to run the code when a new buffer is opened? How does `uniquely` do it? I tried reading its source, but I can't seem to find where the code gets triggered to run.

Thanks

Comment: You provide no link for `uniquely`. Do you expect people who might help you to google for `projectile` and `uniquely`?

Comment: @Drew I'm not expecting anything..
Projectile: https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile/blob/42e991af5d915d4ac77e275f862c907366fc6f5d/projectile.el 
Uniquely: https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/0537943561a37b54467bec19d1b8afbeba8e1e58/lisp/uniquify.el

Comment: Thanks. I think that might help get you more & better answers. It was just a suggestion. Sorry if it sounded like a rebuke.

Comment: I would recommend you try smart-mode-line. By default, it displays file paths relative to the projectile project.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can advise `create-file-buffer`, if you care only about file buffers.
Likewise, you can advise `rename-buffer`.

That's what `uniquify` does, for instance. Are you familiar with `uniquify.el`? Maybe it offers all that you need. See the Emacs manual, node [**`Uniquify`**](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Uniquify.html).

Comment: Any idea how one would do it for non-file buffers?  I seem to recall seeing a S.O. thread a long while back that said it couldn't be done, but I could easily be misremembering.

Comment: @Dan: AFAIK, there is no single function that all buffer-creation goes through. But you can try advising `get-buffer-create`. That's written in C, however. You can certainly advise `generate-new-buffer`, which calls `get-buffer-create`. (But you might also ask yourself whether you really need this for non-file buffers.)

Comment: Yes, I am familiar I read through the source and couldn't figure it out. I never heard of `advise` before so I will take a look at what that means. I think this solves it. Thanks!

Comment: `advice-add` is the new way to advise. But you can still use `defadvice` (which is good).