# Template for new file

Tags: find-file, template

When opening a new file of certain types, I would like some boilerplate to be inserted. That is, when opening a buffer for a file that does not yet exist, insert some predefined text, optionally with some variable interpolation.

Things I can think of as use case:

- Insert some license text at the start
- Insert `#IF_DEFINED_FOO_H` directives in new C header files.
- Insert some basic targets in a new Makefile

Comment: This sounds similar to what you are asking: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/10457/563 except it is about modifying modeline appearance rather than buffer contents, but the procedure would be the same.

Comment: https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoInsertMode

Answer (score 7):

See standard library `auto-insert.el`, which is part of Emacs.  To use it, customize options `auto-insert` and `auto-insert-directory`, then do this:

```
(add-hook 'find-file-hook 'auto-insert)
```

---

> `auto-insert` is a variable defined in `autoinsert.el`.
>
> Its value is `not-modified`
>
> Documentation:
>
> Controls automatic insertion into newly found empty files.
>
> Possible values:
>
> - `nil` - do nothing
> - `t` - insert if possible
> - other - insert if possible, but mark as unmodified.
>
> Insertion is possible when something appropriate is found in
>   `auto-insert-alist`.  When the insertion is marked as unmodified, you can
>   save it with  `C-x C-w RET`.
>
> This variable is used when the function `auto-insert` is called, e.g.
>   when you do `(add-hook 'find-file-hook 'auto-insert)`.
>   With `M-x auto-insert`, this is always treated as if it were `t`.
>
> You can customize this variable.

---

> `auto-insert-directory` is a variable defined in `autoinsert.el`.
>
> Its value is `"~/insert/"`
>
> Documentation:
>
> Directory from which auto-inserted files are taken.
>
> The value must be an absolute directory name;
>   thus, on a GNU or Unix system, it must end in a slash.
>
> You can customize this variable.

See also [`header2.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/header2.el).

Comment: You can also combine `auto-insert.el` with [Yasnippet](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Yasnippet) (for example) to get dynamic or interactive configuration of your boilerplate.

Comment: @nega: You might want to post that comment as another answer.

Answer (score 7):

At @Drew's suggestion, here's a short example of combining [YASnippet](https://github.com/joaotavora/yasnippet) and `auto-insert` to achieve dynamic or interactive boilerplate.

From my `~/.emacs.d/init.el`:

```
;;{{{ yasnippet & auto-insert

(use-package yasnippet
  :config
  (add-to-list 'yas-snippet-dirs "~/.emacs.d/snippets")
  (yas-global-mode 1))

(defun nega/yas-cmake-bp ()
  (interactive)
  (yas-expand-snippet (yas-lookup-snippet "cmake_minimum_required" 'cmake-mode)))

(use-package autoinsert
  :config
  (setq auto-insert-query nil)
  (auto-insert-mode 1)
  (add-hook 'find-file-hook 'auto-insert)
  (setq auto-insert-alist nil) ;; remove this like to restore defaults
  (add-to-list 'auto-insert-alist  '("CMakeLists\\.txt$" . [nega/yas-cmake-bp])))

;;}}}
```

Block-by-block, we:

- Load `yasnippet`, set the user-defined snippet location to `~/.emacs.d/snippets`, and enable `yasnippet` globally
- Define a callable function that "executes" the snippet named "cmake_minimum_required" from the "cmake-mode" snippet table
- Load `autoinsert` and configure it to

  - Do not ask when inserting
  - Enable `auto-insert-mode` globally
  - Run auto-insert when a new file is opened
  - Delete any default "auto inserts"
  - Add a filespec + function pair to the list of "auto inserts"

With these three blocks of elisp, every time I open a *new* file named "CMakeLists.txt", the following YASnippet snippet will be "executed" and the corresponding text will be inserted in to the new buffer.

```
# name: cmake_minimum_required
# key: cmr
# --
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION ${1:`cmake-mode-cmake-version`}${2: FATAL_ERROR})
$0
```

The buffer for my new "CMakeLists.txt" looks like:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11.1 FATAL_ERROR)
                               ^
```

The cursor is at the location of the carrot, ie: before the "3". My snippet has found the current version of CMake on my system, and inserted it at that point. This is an editable field, so I change it if I wish. If I edit it, or not, I hit <kbd>TAB</kbd> to move to the next field, which is " FATAL_ERROR". (Yes, in this case it contains the space.)

`FATAL_ERROR` is an optional argument to `cmake_minimum_required()`. If I want to keep it, I can press <kbd>TAB</kbd> again or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> to delete it. Either way the cursor moves to first column of the second line, and we're ready to continue typing.

Note that you can have "traditional auto inserts" and "YASnippet auto inserts" in `auto-insert-alist`. But, you will run into trouble if your filespecs overlap.

Comment: FWIW it'd be more "correct" to use `:hook (find-file . auto-insert)` than doing `add-hook` in custom.